# Postgresql and relation table

Tags: postgresql

I use a postgresql, and creat some tables.
There is users' table

```
CREATE TABLE myschem.users (
  id serial NOT NULL, name character varying(255),email character varying(255)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
```

..and there is a books table

```
CREATE TABLE myschem.books (
  id serial NOT NULL, title character varying(255),author character varying(255)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );
```

And i try to make a relation table

```
CREATE TABLE myschem.bookloans
(
  uid integer, -- user id
  bid integer, -- book id
  primary key (uid, bid),
  FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES myschem.users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (bid) REFERENCES myschem.rooms (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

How to do better that it does not show message:

```
ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"
```

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreign key cannot reference a non unique field, since it needs to reference a *unique* row.

You'll either need to make the referenced field a `PRIMARY KEY`;

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

...or just make it `UNIQUE`;

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id serial NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

[An SQLfiddle showing both versions working to create the tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b15c9/1).